# How do I initiate particles to grow from anywhere on stage upon mouseClick?

Tags: java, processing, mouselistener

I want to be able to create new particles from wherever I click on stage. I'm just stuck on adding the mouse portion and I've tried to add/pass parameters and I always get errors while I try setting the parameters. Any suggestions?

This is my current code:

```
float parSpeed = 1; //speed of particles
int   nParticles = 1000; //# of particles
Particle[] particles;

void setup() {
  size(700,700); //size of image (8.5 x 11 @ 300px) is 3300,2550)
  frameRate(60); //framerate of stage
  background(0); //color of background
  particles = new Particle[nParticles];

//start particle array
for(int i=0; i<nParticles; i++) {
    particles[i] = new Particle();
  }
}

void draw() {
  fill(0,0,0,5); //5 is Alpha
  rect(0,0,width,height); //color of rectangle on top?
  translate(width/2, height/2); //starting point of particles

//start particle array
  for(int i=0; i<nParticles; i++) {
    particles[i].update();
    particles[i].show();
  }
}

//Particle Class
class Particle {
  PVector pos; //position
  float angle; //angle
  float dRange; //diameter range
  float dAngle; //beginning angle?
  color c; //color

  Particle() {
    pos = new PVector(0,0);//new position for the particles.
    angle  = 1; //controls randomization of direction in position when multiplied
    dRange = 0.01; // how big of a circle shold the particles rotate on
    dAngle = 0.15; // -- maximum angle when starting
    c = color(0,0,random(100, 255)); //set color to random blue
  }

  void update() {
    float cor = .25*dRange*atan(angle)/PI; 
    float randNum = (random(2)-1)*dRange-cor;  //Random number from (-dRange, dRange)
    dAngle+=randNum;                       //We don't change the angle directly
                                       //but its differential - source of the smoothness!

    angle+=dAngle;                         //new angle is angle+dAngle -- change angle each frame

    pos.x+=parSpeed*cos(angle);//random direction for X axis multiplied by speed
    pos.y+=parSpeed*sin(angle);//rabdin durectuib for y axis multiplied by speed
  }

void show() {
    fill(c); //fill in the random color
    noStroke(); //no stroke
    ellipse(pos.x,pos.y,10,10); //make the shape
    smooth(); //smooth out the animation
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  print("pressed " + int(key) + " " + keyCode);
  if (key == 's' || key == 'S'){
    saveFrame("image-##.png");
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
   print("mouse has been clicked!"); 
}
```

Comment: [tag:javascript] tag removed as I don't see how your code above has any relationship to this programming language. Please clarify this for me if I deleted the tag in error.

Comment: What GUI library are you using? If you're getting errors with this code, it would be wise to show the error text.

Comment: Edit: I see, you're using the Processing language, but it doesn't appear that you're using the JavaScript port, Processing.js, and so I removed that tag too.

Comment: Processing, yes, sorry, I thought JS had similar syntax and thought it could apply to this as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite the [mouseReleased](http://processing.org/reference/mouseReleased_.html)() method:

In there you'll need to:

1. capture the position of the mouse
2. create the new particle
3. update the position of the newly created particle.
4. add it to the array (the particle system)

This may look simple but you'll have to keep in mind an array cannot change sizes. I would advise that you create a ParticleSystem class that takes care of adding and removing particles from the system.

**Edit:** You might want to consider using an ArrayList instead of an Array of Particles. Have a look at [this](http://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html)

In pseudo code this would look like this:

```
void mouseReleased() {
    int particleX = mouseX;
    int particleY = mouseY;

    Particle P = new Particle(); 
    P.setPos ( new PVector ( particleX, particleY ) ); // this needs to be implemented

    ParticleSystem.add ( P ); // this needs to be implemented
}
```

I hope this will be a good start.

AH

Comment: Awesome, thank you, will look into it! 

I tried the ArrayList method, but don't fully understand it yet, might have to play with it some more.